How to set "canonical: false" when adding a custom repository with the CLI interface?
Is it possible to add canonical: false when adding a repository via CLI, I have searched, but it looks like it has to be manually added?
composer config repositories.test composer https://repo.example.com 


Miller, any feedback on the answer below? I see that you don't seem to have cast a vote on it, despite accepting it. Didn't you find it useful?

If you need to modify any other option, you can pass a JSON object.
E.g., in your case it would be something along the lines of:
composer config repositories.test \
   '{"type": "composer", "url": "https://repo.example.com", "canonical": false}' 


